# Avoid MS Outlook 2010 Rules conflict on multiple computers

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a rule set up in Outlook to move emails with a certain subject line into a specific folder.  It works great and has for years.  The issue is that I often leave Outlook open on my work computer and then have it open at home as well.  Then when one of these emails comes in, BOTH computers "move" it to the specified folder, creating two copies of each such email.  I expect that there is no real solution, since rules process much faster than message synchronization...but does anyone have any ideas on stopping the duplication when both computers are running on the same account at the same time?

Comment: It sounds like the simplest solution is don't leave outlook open at work.  There are also add-ons that can get rid of duplicate emails automatically.

Comment: I don't leave it open on purpose, but sometimes forget to shut down my computer when I leave work in the evening...or sometimes I check my email while at home for lunch...